# htmlagilitypack parse table by th

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the following table using the htmlagilitypack.

```
    <tr>
      <th>
        Anställda:
      </th>
      <td>
        0 - 4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Oms (tkr):
      </th>
      <td>
        5 409
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Im trying to extract the value for **Oms (tkr)**: (in this case **5 409**)

The below code gives me the above html table. Problem is I grab the Oms (tkr) value out. It should also be said that Oms (tkr) is not always on the same place, it can be further down or further up in the table. By this i mean that Oms can sometimes be where Anställda is and so forth.

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode graf in (IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>)doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id=\"info\"]//table")) {
var tabellHTdML = graf.InnerHtml;
MessageBox.Show(tabellHTdML);

}
```

I've tried to do:

```
if (tabellHTML.Contains("Oms"))
{
item.OMS = cells.InnerText;
}
```

But cant seem to get the correct value..any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.htm");

Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//th[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), 'Oms')]").InnerHtml.Trim());
```

will dump this:

```
Oms (tkr)
```

But you'll have to parse the end manually. The Html Agility Pack only knows about elements and attributes. The [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) expression means: select any TH element that has a text content that starts with 'Oms', once trimmed (normalize-space).